# How I can install Akira software?

Tags: 18.04

I want to install Akira UI design software.

This software requires a dependency, meson, and this dependency should be version 0.48.2 or higher, but I cannot find this version for Ubuntu 18.04 in main repository or PPA.

How I can solve this problem with meson and then install Akira?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meson is available from source on PyPi. To install it, run the following:

```
pip3 install meson
```

Make sure you're using the Python 3 version of Pip.